# For loop in my __init__ doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, for-loop

```
    class DictionnaireOrdonne:
        """Classe permettant de créer un dictionnaire ordonné comme une liste, avec des indices"""

        def __init__(self, **keys_values):
            """classe prennent un nombre indéfinit de paramètres nommées"""

            self.keys_values = keys_values
            self._dictionnaire = self.keys_values
            for keys in self.keys_values:
                self.keys = keys

        def __repr__(self):
            """Cette méthode est appelée quand on appelle l'objet"""

            return str(self.keys_values)

        def __getitem__(self, key):
            """Cette méthode spéciale est appelée quand on fait objet[index]
                    Elle redirige vers self._dictionnaire[index]"""

            return self._dictionnaire[key]

        def __setitem__(self, key, value):
            """Cette méthode est appelée quand on écrit objet[index] = valeur
                    On redirige vers self._dictionnaire[index] = valeur"""

            self._dictionnaire[key] = value


test = DictionnaireOrdonne(one=1, two=2, three=3)
print(test.keys)
```

When I run this code, I get:

```
three
```

I only get one of the 3 keys, and it's the last one, i don't know why.

However, when if I modify my for loop to this:

```
for keys in self.keys_values:
        print(keys)
```

Then I get:

```
one
two
three
```

I get the output wanted, but I can't use it because it will print itself without me calling it.

Why do I get only get one key in my first example, and how can I make it so that I get my three keys when I call `test.keys`?

Comment: You aren't appending to a list of keys; you are simply overwriting each previous key with the current key. That said, if you are storing the keyword arguments in `self.key_values`, there's little value to storing them again in `self._dictionnaire` or in redundantly storing the keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a close look at what you're trying to get your for-loop to do:

```py
for keys in self.keys_values:
    self.keys = keys
```

You are *not* appending to a list, or anything of the sort, rather you are replacing the `keys` value with the latest object from `keys_values`.

<s>Quite frankly, you don't actually need a for loop here at all. Simply just set `self.keys` to `self.keys_values`, and it'll work how you want it to.</s>

Edit:

In order to convert the `**keys_values` into a list of keys, use `list()`

```py
self.keys = list(self.keys_values.keys()) # converts the keys into a list

# later on

print(keys) # [ "one", "two", "three" ]
```

Comment: Hello and thanks. If I set `self.keys` to `self.keys_values` then call `test.keys`, I will get both my keys and my values when I only want my keys. Can't I make it so that using the for loop or an other method I capture all my keys?

Comment: Oh alright, for that simply `list(self.keys_values.keys)`. It will pack all your keys (one, two, three) in a list.

Answer (score 1):

Change the code below in `__init__`:

```
for keys in self.keys_values:
    self.keys = keys
```

To:

```
self.keys = self.keys_values
```